# Use LIKE in column with arabic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation, string-searching

I have a SQL Server 2012 DB with a column that includes Arabic text.  The column is nvarchar(MAX) with collation Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS.  To test if LIKE searches are working I copied some of the text from the column and pasted it into a query as follows

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn like N'%arabic_text%'
```

I can visually see the text in the column, but the query returns no results.  Searching for latin characters in the column works fine.

What else can I try?

Comment: **1)** try using `Arabic_100_CI_AI_KS_WS` instead as it is newer and more likely to have proper sort weights defined. **2)** please post some example strings from your column for us to test with.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I'm not allowed to share the actual data.  I can tell you the table is full of snapshots of web pages including the full HTML source and a bunch of metadata.  The column that's not working is the full HTML source column.  It does work if I put the exact same raw text in with no HTML.

Comment: ? You don't have a single value in the table that you can jumble up and provide us with a repro? Seriously? It seems like you only need a string with a single character embedded. How a single character could be considered proprietary, secret data, I have no idea. "Hey Verizon, when I call a certain number, I get disconnected." Verizon: "Can you tell us a number that this happens with?" Me: "No." Verizon: "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"

Comment: So you can't post one value from that HTML source column? Can you reproduce the problem with a subset of the actual data in that column, and post that subset? Also, regarding trying other Collations, you would add the following to the end of your query: `COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AI_KS_WS_SC`. Also try: `COLLATE Arabic_100_BIN2`.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe it is too late for an answer, but I suggest the following solution:

```
"SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyColumn LIKE N'" & MYTEXTBOX & "%';"
```

In this context MYTEXTBOX is not a built in keyword in the query; it is an external variable. I use this solution always and it works, especially when building a complex search criteria, and it work with all versions.

Comment: Creating dynamic SQL by concatenation is vulnerable to SQL injections, so it should be avoided. What's more, this doesn't really address the issue why looking for Arabic text fails.